Removing Parallel Footpaths and Pedestrian Paths from Residential Streets in QGIS
I’m working on a project in QGIS where I’m creating a map to help navigate neighborhoods. I’m using a shapefile from OpenStreetMap, and I’ve run into a problem with footpaths and pedestrian paths that run parallel to residential streets and secondary streets. These paths are essentially sidewalks, which are too close to the streets, and visually clutter the map, making it harder to read.
I don’t want to completely remove the footpaths and pedestrian paths layer because I think there are still important paths, like those in parks or standalone walkways, that aren’t related to residential streets but still might be useful for orientation.
I’ve tried creating a buffer around the residential streets in EPSG:3857 and using Select by Location to target and delete footpaths within that buffer. The Footpaths and Pedestrian Paths layer is also in EPSG:3857, but this either selects all footpaths or fails to fully capture the parallel paths. I’ve included some screenshots below to show how this has been playing out. I've tried to join the street names between the layers to find overlapping or duplicate features, but the Footpaths and Pedestrian Paths layer doesn’t contain street names, so this method didn’t work either. I also checked the validity of the geometries but couldn’t find any invalid features, then I tried snapping the features, but it changed the geometry in ways I didn’t like, distorting some of the features.
What I’m trying to do is to remove only the footpaths that are parallel or too close to the residential streets while keeping independent footpaths, like those in parks and other areas, intact. Ideally, I’d like to find a more automated solution for this process, rather than going through each path manually.
Do you have any suggestions for a fix, tool, plugin, or method I might have missed?

[


Additionally to buffers you may calculate azimuths for your roads/paths like azimuth(end_point(@geometry), start_point(@geometry)) and remove those which a/ intersects buffers and b/ have same/close azimuth. Those paths which are in parks are probably on different landuse polygon like landuse=grass or maybe they intescests with any specific amenity or leisure like park - should be easy to filter out those.

If the geometry of the line is not too complex (for example, if a line is too long or has too many turns, it needs to be preprocessed, such as using the v.break tool of GRASS to break), I think using distance and angle as constraints can help to filter out parallel lines of a line.
This can be achieved through the following pyqgis code:
First, for each type=2 line (i.e., residential streets and secondary streets mentioned in your question), query the lines that intersect with its buffer at a certain distance.
Then calculate the angle between the vector composed of the first and last points of the current line and the vector composed of the first and last points of the queried type=1 line (i.e. footpaths and pedestrian paths in your question).
Finally, if the angle is also less than the threshold, the line can be marked as parallel (is_parallel=1).
I ran this script with several test data, and the results are shown in the figure, and the expected parallel lines are marked.
import numpy as np
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("test_data")[0]
if 'is_parallel' in layer.fields().names():
    layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([layer.fields().indexFromName('is_parallel')])
    layer.updateFields()
# add a new field
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("is_parallel", QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields()
# create spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures())
# set the distance threshold and angle threshold
distance_threshold = 5.0  # modify it if needed
angle_threshold = 10.0  # modify it if needed
# iterate all features, type=2: the center road, type=1: the road on both sides
layer.startEditing()
for feat1 in layer.getFeatures():
    if feat1["type"] != 2:
        continue
    geom1 = feat1.geometry()
    center1 = geom1.centroid().asPoint()
    buffer_geom1 = geom1.buffer(distance_threshold, 5)
    nearest_ids = index.intersects(buffer_geom1.boundingBox())
    is_parallel = 0
    for feat2_id in nearest_ids:
        feat2 = layer.getFeature(feat2_id)
        if feat2["type"] != 1:
            continue
        geom2 = feat2.geometry()
        vertices = list(geom1.vertices())
        point1 = vertices[0]
        point2 = vertices[-1]
        vector1 = np.array([point2.x() - point1.x(), point2.y() - point1.y()])
        vertices = list(geom2.vertices())
        point1 = vertices[0]
        point2 = vertices[-1]
        vector2 = np.array([point2.x() - point1.x(), point2.y() - point1.y()])
        angle_degrees = np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(vector1, vector2) / (np.linalg.norm(vector1) * np.linalg.norm(vector2))))
        if angle_degrees <= angle_threshold:
            is_parallel = 1
            # update attribute
            layer.changeAttributeValue(feat2_id, feat1.fieldNameIndex("is_parallel"), is_parallel)
layer.commitChanges()
print("Done!")


